# customise 404 html error page in mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

How to use customise html error page for 404 request.

currently my error request showing me   error  page with 404 request.

//I want to show my custom  page with same request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the customErrors in Web.config to set your custom error page for every kind of  http error, it works for all ASP.NET Request:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="Errors/500.aspx">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="Errors/500.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/404.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="Errors/403.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

See MSDN LINK:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx

Or you can use Add ErrorFilterAttribute into global filters in MVC runtime:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute());
```

Then add a "Error.cshtml" view file to "/Views/Shared/" Folder , Here is example

```
@model object
@{
    var context = this.ApplicationInstance.Context;
    var ex = (Model is HandleErrorInfo ? ((HandleErrorInfo)Model).Exception : (Model as Exception)) ?? context.Server.GetLastError();
}
@(ex.Message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code as your last route to register in global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "404-PageNotFound",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = "StaticContent", action = "PageNotFound" }
    );
```

Refer this: http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/17/strategies-for-resource-based-404-errors-in-aspnet-mvc/

OR

Here are the articles How to create custom error pages with MVC

http://kitsula.com/Article/MVC-Custom-Error-Pages.

Hope this may help You!

Answer (score 0):

Configure the error code in web.xml file
Example:

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>500</error-code>
 <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
 <error-code>503</error-code>
 <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/503.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```